# Getting Zero fee in Stripe Balance Transaction API Response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am using `Stripe` API for receiving the contribution from multiple user. So I want to generate statement for our customer so they can see what exact amount, fee deduction, transaction count etc.

After looked into Stripe API I found there are two API(`Stripe::Transfer` and `Stripe::BalanceTransaction`) these can be used to fullfil my requirement.

So as per documentation [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#transfers)  I am calling `Stripe::Transfer`  API and this API returning correct response like below

```
transfer = #<Stripe::Transfer:0x3f997455ac88 id=tr_1xxxxxxxxxxxxxx>    JSON: {
"id": "tr_1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"object": "transfer",
"amount": 9510,
"amount_reversed": 0,
"application_fee": null,
"balance_transaction": "txn_123",
"created": 1477485158,
"currency": "usd",
"date": 1477485158,
"description": null,
"destination": "acct_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"destination_payment": "py_xxxxxxxxxxx",
"failure_code": null,
"failure_message": null,
"livemode": false,
"metadata": {},
"method": "standard",
"recipient": null,
"reversals": {"object":"list","data":[],"has_more":false,"total_count":0,"url":"/v1/transfers/tr_xx/reversals"},
"reversed": false,
"source_transaction": "ch_xxxxxxxxx",
"source_type": "card",
"statement_descriptor": null,
"status": "paid",
"type": "stripe_account"
}
```

I am calling Stripe::BalanceTransaction API to get the details particular transfer's transactions

```
balance_transaction_id = transfer.balance_transaction
Stripe::BalanceTransaction.retrieve(balance_transaction_id)
```

Getting below response

```
#<Stripe::BalanceTransaction:0x3f9974f2f1c8 id=txn_123> JSON: {
"id": "txn_123",
"object": "balance_transaction",
"amount": -9510,
"available_on": 1478044800,
"created": 1477485158,
"currency": "usd",
"description": null,
"fee": 0,
"fee_details": [

],
"net": -9510,
"source": "tr_xxxxxxxx",
"sourced_transfers": {"object":"list","data":  [],"has_more":false,"total_count":0,"url":"/v1/transfers?  source_transaction=tr_xxxx"},
"status": "available",
"type": "transfer"
}
```

I setup application fee(2%) and this showing correct on Stripe Dashboard but in the above response I am getting `fee` is `0`

So how can I get `fee` and `total_count` values in this response?

Comment: Can any one help me what should I do full fill my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to look at the transfer and its balance transaction here to get the fees. This is an automatic transfer between accounts from a destination payment so there is no fee linked to it.

You need to retrieve the original charge in `source_transaction` and then look at this charge's own `balance_transaction` and `application_fee` objects.

You can even use the expand feature to do this in one API call:
https://stripe.com/docs/api#expanding_objects

Regarding the total count I suspect you want the number of transactions for this user, then you need to look at this when listing all transfers to this account and add the following optional parameter to the request:

```
:include => ['total_count']
```

This would only work if you don't create manual transfers to the connected account on top of destination charges though.